# How valuable is a Dream Job? (vs skill)

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

Sounds like, based on [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/69457/dream-job-vs-skill-level-9) it was a matter on contention in Tiny Tower.

If it works the same in Tiny Death Star it would seem the floors total skill acts as a percentage discount on all stocking times while a dream job could be thought of as a "50% discount" on one item being stocked.

So, 1 skill point is worth 1% and a dream job is worth ~%17 which suggests that a dream job is more important than any skill considerations.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I would say that **the bitizen with the dream job** is *more valuable* than a highly skilled bitizen.

For example, a highly skilled bitizen would complete the job of ordering 100 items in, lets say, 10 minutes instead of 15, which isn't a bad deal.

**BUT** if another bitizen (even if they have low skills) dreamed of working in that level they would order *double* the amount of items in 15 minutes, creating 200. This equals more credits and more time between the next order. **Plus**, whenever you reward a bitizen with their dream job you get handed an imperial bux that you can save towards a better elevator (I've already bought the 75 bux one).

In short

- Level 9 bitizen = **Less ordering time, normal amount of items**
- Dream job bitizen = **Normal ordering time, more amount of items, free imperial bux**

You may also be lucky enough to come across a level 9 bitizen with a dream job.

Happy gaming! :)

Answer (score 0):

Its very important to put your bitizen in the dream job if only for a moment get your buck and then you can evict or relocate.  If every bitizen hasen't made you a buck then you are giving away money.